# "windows is searching for a solution" popup box

Tags: windows-7

when a program crashes in windows 7 there is a popup box that happens: "Windows is searching for a solution to this problem"  It never finds a solution and I have to waste a click closing it.  As I am using the Beta Visual Studio, I see this box once or twice a day.

I have never seen it find a solution and I don't think that it will.  Can I disable it?

Comment: Actually it _has_ found a solution quite a few times for me... especially driver issues that cause some system program (like svchost) to crash.

Comment: When that box shows up it is sending information as well as searching. You may not always get an answer immediately, but you will almost always find something in the action center within a week or so. I would of course advise that you continue to send crash information (especially for a beta) so that the final build can resolve your issues. Or you could not, and be part of the "ms products suck" crowd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the registry, go to key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting and add the REG_DWORD value DontShowUI = 1

[As answered on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/30177/disabling-process-crash-dialogs-on-vista) by Lev

Comment: Any information on whether or not this causes it to automatically send crash information? If so I'd use it, but if it does not send data because it is disabled that would make it worthless for me (since, I think any developer would agree, getting as much crash data as possible is good for a product's life cycle).

Comment: While I agree sending the data would be helpful there is nothing more frustrating that watching that dialog spin endlessly only to (in my experience **never** find a solution) - worst case scenario I'd like an option to auto-re-start the application while it wastes time looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative solution to this problem that is visible in the user interface.

1. Go to Action Center
2. Go to Change Action Center settings
3. Under 'Related Settings', go to Problem reporting settings
4. Change to 'Never check for solutions'

This solution is described in more detail on the webpage: [TechSpot  Disable “Windows is checking for a solution…” message after a program crashes](http://www.techspot.com/blog/671/disable-windows-is-checking-for-a-solution-message-after-a-program-crashes/)

Comment: Is there a similar UI-based solution for Windows 10?